# Tradingview Pine script -- Line 15: Syntax error at input ')'

Tags: formatting, pine-script

I tried everything I know but it still gives me this error. Help please. Thank you in advance.

(Stack is not letting me post this with the following error with the message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So I'm repeating this message several times -- please ignore. "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.")

```
//@version=5
```

```
indicator(title='Hull MA Multi-Time Frame', shorttitle='HMA MTF', overlay=false)

PDS = input.int(7, title = "Periods (PDS)", minval=2)
SRC = input(close, title='Source')

HMA1_res = input.timeframe('15', title = "HMA1")
HMA2_res = input.timeframe('30', title = "HMA2")
HMA3_res = input.timeframe('60', title = "HMA3")
HMA4_res = input.timeframe('240', title = "HMA4")

f_HMA(_PDS, _SRC) =>
    _xHMA = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(_SRC, _PDS / 2) - ta.wma(_SRC, _PDS), math.round(math.sqrt(_PDS))))
    _xHMA_is_up = _HMA >= _xHMA[1]
    [_xHMA, _xHMA_is_up]


[xHMA1, _xHMA1_is_up] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HMA1_res, f_HMA(PDS, SRC))
HMA1_color = xHMA1_is_up ? color.green : color.red
HMA1_text = f_res_to_string(HMA1_res) + "=" + str.tostring(xHMA1, "#.00")
plot(xHMA1, color = HMA1_color, linewidth=1)
var label HMA1_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, color = #00000000, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_left)
label.set_xy(HMA1_label, x = bar_index, y = xHMA1)
label.set_textcolor(HMA1_label, HMA1_color)
label.set_text(HMA1_label, HMA1_text)


[xHMA2, _xHMA2_is_up] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HMA2_res, f_HMA(PDS, SRC))
HMA2_color = xHMA2_is_up ? color.green : color.red
HMA2_text = f_res_to_string(HMA2_res) + "=" + str.tostring(xHMA2, "#.00")
plot(xHMA2, color = HMA2_color, linewidth=1)
var label HMA2_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, color = #00000000, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_left)
label.set_xy(HMA2_label, x = bar_index, y = xHMA2)
label.set_textcolor(HMA2_label, HMA2_color)
label.set_text(HMA2_label, HMA2_text)

[xHMA3, _xHMA3_is_up] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HMA3_res, f_HMA(PDS, SRC))
HMA3_color = xHMA3_is_up ? color.green : color.red
HMA3_text = f_res_to_string(HMA3_res) + "=" + str.tostring(xHMA3, "#.00")
plot(xHMA3, color = HMA3_color, linewidth=1)
var label HMA3_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, color = #00000000, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_left)
label.set_xy(HMA3_label, x = bar_index, y = xHMA3)
label.set_textcolor(HMA3_label, HMA3_color)
label.set_text(HMA3_label, HMA3_text)

[xHMA4, _xHMA4_is_up] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HMA4_res, f_HMA(PDS, SRC))
HMA4_color = xHMA4_is_up ? color.green : color.red
HMA4_text = f_res_to_string(HMA4_res) + "=" + str.tostring(xHMA4, "#.00")
plot(xHMA4, color = HMA4_color, linewidth=1)
var label HMA4_label = label.new(x = na, y = na, color = #00000000, size = size.normal, style = label.style_label_left)
label.set_xy(HMA4_label, x = bar_index, y = xHMA4)
label.set_textcolor(HMA4_label, HMA4_color)
label.set_text(HMA4_label, HMA4_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put your cursor to the right of the () it will highlight the other end if theres one to close it try removing the extra one

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUrY5.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[Code =D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWaqR.png)
I was in a good mood you were pretty close.. pretty sure its what you were trying to get.. only had to add a x to the  _(x)HMA >= in the function
and remove the f_string function thing because the timeframes are already strings
and the extra )

Looks interesting whats the idea behind this if you dont mind me asking?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. See [answer].

Comment: ANSWERED!  Thank you FFriZz. Your change corrected the script. It works!